# Php encrypt with RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

Have been trying to encrypt a 64 byte string of data with a publickey in php, but no matter what I try the result is rejected by the receiver. I been using phpseclib,

```
    $key = PublicKeyLoader::load("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");

$key->withPadding(RSA::ENCRYPTION_OAEP)->withHash('sha256')->withMGFHash('sha1');
    
    $random_key = bin2hex(random_bytes(64));
    
    $generatekey = base64_encode($key->encrypt($random_key));
```

But no luck. When I do it through this website, https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption, the output string works. So do anyone know how this can be done? Any help much appriciated.

Comment: Use SHA-1 instead of SHA-256 in the `withHash` call?

Comment: No unfortunately that doesn't change anything. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Instead of sha256, sha1 must be applied (s. 1st comment). That it doesn't work with this fix alone is due to a 2nd bug. Your 2nd line goes nowhere, you must assign the result of the 2nd line to a variable that will be used later for the encryption: `$key = $key->withPadding(RSA::ENCRYPTION_OAEP)->withHash('sha1')->withMGFHash('sha1');`. With this, decryption is successful (e.g. on the linked website).

Comment: Well, I would assign it not to `$key` but to `$algo` maybe and use that as `$algo->encrypt` (or `$cipher->encrypt`), makes more sense to me.

Comment: Thanks so much, what a stupid mistake. Thanks again. You just saved my day.

Comment: From your latest comment it sounds like you got it working _but_...  `$key->withPadding(RSA::ENCRYPTION_OAEP)->withHash('sha256')->withMGFHash('sha1');`...  you should assign the result of that to `$key. `$key` is immutable and `withHash` / `withPadding` doesn't modify `$key` so much as it returns a new _instance_ of `$key`